# How to get the list item name from a listview to a textview in another activity?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, listview

Im creating an app where users can enter the movies they own, to show in a listview, and for random picking a movie from that list.

Now what my problem is, that when clicking on an item in the listview a new activity opens op where the item clicked is the title in a textview. So far i can get the movie from the list who is number 1 to show, but that shows it's title no matter which list item I click, how can i get the specific name depending on what item is clicked?? Thanks in advance.

My Database class:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class MovieDatabaseHelper {

    private static final String TAG = MovieDatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    // database configuration
    // if you want the onUpgrade to run then change the database_version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymoviedatabase.db";

    // table configuration
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "movie_table";         // Table name
    private static final String MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_ID = "_id";     // a column named "_id" is required for cursor
    private static final String MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE = "movie_title";
    private static final String MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_YEAR = "production_year";

    private DatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    // this is a wrapper class. that means, from outside world, anyone will communicate with MovieDatabaseHelper,
    // but under the hood actually DatabaseOpenHelper class will perform database CRUD operations 
    public MovieDatabaseHelper(Context aContext) {

        openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(aContext);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertData (String aMovieTitle, String aMovieYear) {

        // we are using ContentValues to avoid sql format errors

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE, aMovieTitle);
        contentValues.put(MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_YEAR, aMovieYear);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
    //Retrieves all the records 
    public Cursor getAllData () {

        String buildSQL = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE";

        Log.d(TAG, "getAllData SQL: " + buildSQL);

        return database.rawQuery(buildSQL, null);
    }


//    Retrieves specific record  
    public String getMovieTitle()
        {
        Cursor c =          
                database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                        new String[] { MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE }, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst())
            return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE ));
        else
            return "Nothing";

        }


//    Retrieves a random entry from the Database 
    public String getRandomMovie()
    {
    Cursor c = database.query(TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",
            new String[] { MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE  }, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c.moveToFirst())
      return c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE ));
    else 
      return "nothing";
    }


    //Check if record exist

  //---deletes a particular record---
    public void delete(int _id) 
    {
        database.delete(TABLE_NAME, MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_ID+"="+_id, null);

    }

    //---updates a record---
    public boolean updateRecord(long _id, String movie_title) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE, movie_title);
        return database.update(TABLE_NAME, args, MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + "=" + _id, null) > 0;
    }



    // this DatabaseOpenHelper class will actually be used to perform database related operation 

    private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context aContext) {
            super(aContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            // Create your tables here

            String buildSQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " + MOVIE_TABLE_COLUMN_YEAR + " TEXT )";

            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Database schema upgrade code goes here

            String buildSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

            Log.d(TAG, "onUpgrade SQL: " + buildSQL);

            sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(buildSQL);       // drop previous table

            onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);               // create the table from the beginning
        }
    }
}
```

My listview class:

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
//import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
    private MovieDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private static final int ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private ListView listView;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    private static final String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dblist);

        databaseHelper = new MovieDatabaseHelper(this);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.cartoon015);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_data);
        ImageButton okay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.okay);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {


                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,IMDb.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Log.d(TAG, "clicked on item: " + position);
            }
        }
);


        okay.setOnClickListener
        (new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setVolume((float) 0.3, (float) 0.3);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this,MovieActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        );



        // Database query can be a time consuming task ..
        // so its safe to call database query in another thread
        // Handler, will handle this stuff for you <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley">

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, databaseHelper.getAllData());
                listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickEnterData(View btnAdd) {

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MyActivity.this, R.raw.cartoon015);
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume((float) 0.1, (float) 0.1);

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EnterDataActivity.class), ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == ENTER_DATA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            databaseHelper.insertData(data.getExtras().getString("tag_movie_title"), data.getExtras().getString("tag_movie_year"));

            customAdapter.changeCursor(databaseHelper.getAllData());
        }
    }
}
```

My movie detail class:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IMDb extends Activity {

    TextView Movietitle;
    private MovieDatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    MediaPlayer mp;




    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.imdb);

        Movietitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.movietitle);
        databaseHelper = new MovieDatabaseHelper(this);
        Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);


        Movietitle.setText( databaseHelper.getMovieTitle());


        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is lot of code you are asking for. But I can tell you the steps

1. Create a Model Class for your movie,, where you can hold the db records
2. Create list of Model Class and then when you click the item, you get the position of record in list.
3. Your movie Model class must have getter and setter functions to retrieve record details.